# Unable to connect to a remote machine using RemoteWebdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, remotewebdriver

As i am new to selenium WebDriver, Remote Webdriver and WebDriverManager, i have issues connecting from hub to the node. This is how my design looks like -

I have a code base which runs on linux based machines. Now, I go ahead and git clone the selenium repository on linux machine . I would want to establish that linux machine as a hub. So start the selenium Standalone server on the linux machine as below -

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role hub
```

Now i have Windows based machines which i communicate using Remote Desktop Connection application
and i consider them as nodes and on one of the windows based machine i start the selenium standalone server as a node like below -

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -role node -hub http://<public ip of linux hub machine>:4444/grid/register/
```

For both i get the successful connection
Linux Machine -
[image]

Windows Machine -
[image]

I try to execute below code -

```
@Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException
    {   
        System.out.println("Sample Test");
        String s1 = System.getProperty("user");
        String s2 = System.getProperty("pass");
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++SETTING UP OPTIONS+++++++++++++");
        //FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<IP_LINUXMACHINE>:4444/wd/hub"),options);
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++SETTING UP WEBDRIVER +++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        //WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().capabilities(options).remoteAddress("http://<IP_LINUXMACHINE:4444/wd/hub").create(); 
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
```

Below is the MVN command -

`mvn -f pom.xml -pl FrontEndTestsRepo,SharedLibrariesRepo --am clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile=testsuite.xml -Duser=abc -Dpass=abc@12`

I get below error -

```
brotli4j not in the classpath; Brotli support will be unavailable.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.31 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
test(com.******.mc.tests.common.LoginTests)  Time elapsed: 1.225 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'JENKINS-WIN-S12', ip: '************', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_321'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'uiUbuntu18-102-44-LinuxSlave', ip: '********', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--allow-insecure-localhost, --start-maximized, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --allow-running-insecure-co...], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--allow-insecure-localhost, --start-maximized, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --allow-running-insecure-co...], extensions: []}}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
    at com.*******.mc.tests.common.LoginTests.test(LoginTests.java:47)
```

Got below error on hub

```
Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{goog:chromeOptions={args=[--allow-insecure-localhost, --start-maximized, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --allow-running-insecure-content], extensions=[]}, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserName=chrome}]
11:48:59.308 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platform=VISTA}
```

Comment: Was there anything in node logs at that time?

Comment: Are you using version 103 of chromium, there have been many issues with the chromium drivers (Google, Edge..). Suggest you downgrade to v102 or try the v104 that is in beta (chrome driver already available). See here for issues: stackoverflow.com/a/72852012/11543023